# Android SearchView only briefly displays cursor when I click on search input field, and no keyboard displays. Can't input text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-search

I'm trying to implement a SearchView inside of a layout, not in a menu layout, but when I click on the search input box, the cursor just briefly shows, then disappears, and the keyboard never displays. It seems like its loosing focus possibly? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now with zero luck.

Code is below. Has been edited for clarity.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

layout with SearchView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.163"
        app:queryHint="Search Here" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="362dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--the root view must be the DrawerLayout-->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">




    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <!--this the navigation view which draws
          and shows the navigation drawer-->
    <!--include the menu created in the menu folder-->
    <!--app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"  this goes in nav view if needed-->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


    android:clickable="true"
    >

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
            layout="@layout/nav_choose_foods" />
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter_AllFoods.ItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter_Search.ItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter_Nutrients.ItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter_FoodTotals.ItemClickListener{

    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

  SearchView searchView;


    //JSONObject finalSums = new JSONObject();

    static RecyclerViewAdapter_AllFoods adapter;

    static RecyclerViewAdapter_Nutrients adapter_nutrients;
    static RecyclerViewAdapter_FoodTotals adapter_foodtotals;

    static RecyclerViewAdapter_Search searchList_Recycler_Adapter;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);

        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)action.getCustomView().getParent();
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        toolbar.getContentInsetEnd();
        toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

        //list =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        // pass the Open and Close toggle for the drawer layout listener
        // to toggle the button
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar


        //runProgram();

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        searchList_Recycler_Adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter_Search(this, LoadData.vegListJSON);
        searchList_Recycler_Adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchList_Recycler_Adapter);

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);// searchView is null
        searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        // set up the RecyclerView
       
     

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {


            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just figured this out. It was the line "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" that was screwing things up. Not sure how I missed that.